# Get specific text from textbox using regexp

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regex in C#.net to extract printers from a list in a script.

This is an example:

```vb
@set nr=2
@if not exist "%userprofile%\Version%nr%.txt" goto reload
@goto koppla
:reload
@echo skrivare>"%userprofile%\Version%nr%.txt"
@del "%userprofile%\zxy-*.txt"
@call skrivare.cmd
@exit
:koppla
@%connect1% \\%Print2%\Lund-M1
@%connect2% \\%Print2%\MAR-M1
@%connect2% \\%Print2%\MAR-M2
```

I would like to get the names (Lund-M1, MAR-M1, MAR-M2) of the printers in a array to foreach.

I really appreciate any help on this, my mind doesn't work with Regex.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something quite simple, like searching for the Print2 prefix:

```
\\\\%Print2%\\(.*)
```

This gives the following output on http://www.regexer.com. You'd then need to access the first group of each `Match` object to grab the part of the string you are after.

[image]

**Edit**

If you want to encapsulate different print numbers use the following which allows the 2 to be exchanged with any other number.

```
\\\\%Print[0-9]%\\(.*)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! I forgot to say that in the same script, there could be like @%connect2% \\%Print1%\SAR-P2 also, %Print1% is the difference. Should I do another expression for that or is there a way to implement it in the same search?

Comment: @Andreas: I've added an extra bit at the end to show how you can exchange the number to any other number.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?m:(?<=^@\%connect\d\% \\\\(.*?\\)*)[^\\]+$)
```

will give three matches over your script, with values

```
Lund-M1
MAR-M1
MAR-M2
```

So

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"(?m:(?<=^@\%connect\d\% \\\\(.*?\\)*)[^\\]+$)")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(m => m.Value)
     .ToArray()
```

gives you what you need.

This checks for line starting `@%connect` then any digit followed by `%` then pulls the last segment of any path of the form `\\something\something\something\AnyNonBackslashChars`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, 
    @"^@%connect\d+%\s+\\\\%Print2%\\(.*?)\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline))
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var name = match.Groups[1];
    }
}
```